# Como sumar todos los valores de una columna - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas llamadas **Carteras** y **Solicitudes**. En la tabla solicitudes tengo el campo **amount** que almacena un numero entero en la base de datos.

Una cartera puede tener varias solicitudes y en este caso la cartera San Jacinto tiene 2 solicitudes y la cartera San Martin tiene 3 solicitudes, por eso es que en la vista se aprecian que el mismo numero de datos(Q5000) en las celdas de la columna ***capital invertido***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo obtener la suma de las cantidades que estan encerradas en el circulo celeste?

Este es mi controlador **CarterasController**:

```
public function index()
{
    $carteras = Cartera::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    return view('admin.carteras.index', compact('carteras'));
}
```

**La vista:**

```
<div class="bg-white mt-5 mb-5 table-responsive">
<table class="table text-center table-width">
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Departamento</th>
        <th>Municipio</th>
        <th>Capital Invertido</th>
        <th>Capital+Interés</th>
        <th>Total Amortización</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($carteras as $cartera)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$cartera->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$cartera->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$cartera->depto}}</td>
            <td>{{$cartera->municipio}}</td>
            <td>Q
                //=====Con esto he logrado tomar las cantidades que se muestran======
                @foreach ($cartera->solicitudes as $solicitud)
                    {{$solicitud->amount}}
                @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>Q0000.00</td>
            <td>Q0000.00</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

La Relacion entre tablas en el modelo **Cartera**

```
 public function solicitudes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Credit');
}
```

Intenté hacerlo con la función `sum()` pero no se como utilizarlo porque no mostró lo que necesitaba(siempre en la vista lo hice):

```
 <td>Q
      @foreach ($cartera->solicitudes as $solicitud)
         {{$solicitud->sum('amount')}}
      @endforeach
 </td>
```

me mostraba esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sumaba todos los datos de la tabla y lo que necesito es por ejemplo Q10,000 y Q15,000 respectivamente.

O habrá otra forma de obtener esas cantidades desde el controlador y sumarlas? Estoy iniciando aprender laravel y necesito ayuda por favor :(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de varias formas, quizá hasta con eloquent, pero para que sea entendida de mejor forma podrías  crear una variable `$suma` e ir sumando tus valores en esa variable:

```
@php
    $suma=0;
@endphp
 <td>Q
      @foreach ($cartera->solicitudes as $solicitud)
        @php
          $suma+=$solicitud->amount;//sumanos los valores, ahora solo fata mostrar dicho valor
        @endphp             
      @endforeach
      {{$suma}}
 </td>
```

Eso debería de funcionarte.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que sum() suma toda la columna de la consulta a retornar, lo que deberías hacer es discriminar de acuerdo a los id que correspondan a cada cartera. Podrías usar DB:select() y de esa forma usar sql puro

```
$query = "select 
                carteras.*,
                solicitudes.depto,
                solicitudes.municipio,
               (select 
                      sum(amount)
                from solicitudes 
                where solicitudes.cartera_id = cateras.id) as amount
         from 
               carteras, solicitudes;"

$carteras = DB::select($query)->get();
```

El método select recibe una consulta sql tal cual la escribirías en una línea de comandos de sql, la ejecuta y devuelve una instancia de QueryBuilder. El método get() saca de esa instancia la colección que necesitas iterar en blade.

La vista no cambiaría demasiado:

```
@foreach ($carteras as $cartera)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$cartera->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$cartera->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$cartera->depto}}</td>
            <td>{{$cartera->municipio}}</td>
            <td>Q{{$cartera->amount}}</td>
            <td>Q0000.00</td>
            <td>Q0000.00</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Este enfoque debería solucionar tu problema, sólo deberías cambiar los nombres de columnas por los que tenés en tus tablas.